# PWA shortcut says "app not installed" when clicked

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I found out about PWA shortcuts today and I tried setting it up but I can't figure out how to make it work as I get an error "App Not installed" whenever I click the shortcut.

The website is https://specy.github.io/skyMusic/
my manifest shortcut contains this:

```
shortcuts": [
    {
      "name": "Open composer",
      "short_name": "Composer",
      "description": "Open the composer page",
      "url": "./#/Composer",
      "icons": [{ "src": "manifestData/composerIcon.png", "sizes": "192x192" }]
    }
  ]
```

I think The issue I'm having comes from the react hashrouter, the final link should be https://specy.github.io/skyMusic/#/Composer

Comment: Installs fine in Chrome/Mac. Are you sure you have totally cleared out everything from earlier tests on the device failing? Perhaps try with a device you have not yet tested with to rule this out.

Comment: The installation is not the issue, as that works, the problem comes from the quick shortcuts that you can select to open the page in a certain URL. For example this shortcut I sent would open the /Composer page. I did some big changes to the file structure of the project today so I'll need some testing before I can publish the new version and test again but this time I tried setting the URL as "./Composer" (removing the #), hopefully it works

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: FYI, I filed a bug with chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1324409

Comment: @ConnorClark Nope didn't solve it, I just removed the feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug report and it got the attention of an Android developer (although the bug ticket was never updated). It seems to have been fixed as of  ~May 11th.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1324409